# Connecting a bluetooth module to GPIO?

Tags: gpio, sensor, bluetooth

I got a bluetooth sensor from this [Chinese company](http://www.lctech-inc.com/). Model is BC417. The module has six pins:

- KEY
- RXD
- TXD
- 5.0
- 3.3
- GND

I'm totally newbie about GPIO and sensors, only got that module and a few cables. What should I do to start working with it? How should I plug it, and do I need any resistor? What libraries should I download?

At least I want to be able to emit anything through bluetooth or receive any kind of data from a mobile bluetooth device.

Comment: You should post an answer to the question rather than editing it with an answer.

Comment: I have not time to keep working with it these days, it's not like I already know how to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the module connected, I followed this site [straightforward](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/a-cheap-bluetooth-serial-port-for-your-raspberry-pi). When I scanned with my mobile for connected devices I found **HC-05** which googling I knew it's a an standard for bluetooth module devices.

I already installed `bluetooth` and `bluez-utils` on my Pi.

I used Android blueterm app and logged in into my Pi